# I'm trying to make a formula that checks a number in excel, but the cell has to include the dashes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have something like this:

```
A1: ABC-DE442
B1: 0069-1234-12
```

I'm trying to make a formula that will look at A1, get the number 442, and then check if B1 is in the format of 4 numbers, a dash, 4 numbers, a dash, and then finally 2 numbers. I want to make sure that this could work with any number besides 442 though. So if I had like 123 instead of 442, it would need to be 1 number, dash, 2 numbers, dash, and three numbers.

It would also need to give me an error if I had something like this:

```
A1: ABC-DE442
B1: 004-2345-34
```

because it only has three numbers in the first section before the dash.

Hopefully I have been clear enough in what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any other *rules* besides 442 and 123?

Comment: Well yea it needs to work with any combination of number after the letter in A1. Anything like: 2345, 12...basically any number.

Comment: I don't think a formula will be flexible enough, and possibly a headache to maintain. A VBA script on the other hand would work nice.

Comment: I've never used VBA script before, but I guess I'll start looking it up and learning how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with Excel formulae but it will get a bit complicated. The functions you're probably going to want to make use of are `FIND`, `LEFT`, `LEN`, `MID`, and `VALUE`.

For example,

`C1: =FIND("-",B1)`

will return the position of the first dash in the string to be tested, which for your example is 5. Then

`D1: =LEFT(B1,C1-1)`

would return the characters before that dash, i.e. '0069'. Meanwhile you need to get the lengths of the three runs of digits out of your first string (the one in A1). Will that string always be the same length? If so you can use e.g.

`=VALUE(MID(A1,7,1))`

which returns the 7th character of the string in A1 and converts it to a number (4). Now you can test whether that value is equal to the length of the first run of characters, i.e. `LEN(D1)`.

But are those characters all numeric? Well, you can try converting them to a number with `VALUE(D1)` which will return `#VALUE` if the argument can't be made into a number.

OK, that checked the first run of characters, what about the rest of them? Well,

`=MID(B1,FIND("-",B1)+1,999)`

will give you the remainder of the original string *after* the first dash, which you can analyse in the same way, and so on.

It's easiest to develop these formulae by using lots of cells to hold the intermediate values as you work them out, but once you're confident these are working OK you can consolidate them into fewer cells. Whatever you come up with, make sure you test it with lots of different inputs to check that your formulae respond to them in the way that you expect. (In particular, check what happens if you have one or more spaces after a dash, as `VALUE` will ignore leading spaces - you might want to use a `SUBSTITUTE` function on your initial text to remove any spaces.)

Answer (score 3):

So in the end, this is the giant formula I had to create:

=IF(LEN(LEFT(J4,FIND("-",J4)-1))=VALUE(MID(I4,9,1)),IF(LEN(LEFT(MID(J4,FIND("-",J4)+1,999),FIND("-",MID(J4,FIND("-",J4)+1,999))-1))=VALUE(MID(I4,10,1)),IF(LEN(MID(MID(J4,FIND("-",J4)+1,999),FIND("-",MID(J4,FIND("-",J4)+1,999))+1,999))=VALUE(MID(I4,11,1)),"True","Doesn't match code part 3"),"Doesn't match code part 2"),"Doesn't match code part 1")

```
J15: 0069=LEFT(J5,FIND("-",J5)-1)  
J16: 4=VALUE(MID(I5,7,1))  
J17: 4=LEN(J15)  
J18: 0469-56=MID(J5,FIND("-",J5)+1,999)  
J19: 0469=LEFT(J18,FIND("-",J18)-1)  
J20: 4=VALUE(MID(I5,8,1))  
J21: 4=LEN(J19)  
J22: 56=MID(J18,FIND("-",J18)+1,999)  
J23: 2=VALUE(MID(I5,9,1))  
J24: 2=LEN(J22)
```

Hopefully all of these formulas will make it easier to understand how I combined everything together.

I essentially put every formula into one giant one using the information used in the answer I said was right. For the first part, I took the LEN(D1) but had it all written out, and then set it equal to the =VALUE(MID(A1,7,1)).

Then, for the true part of that if statement, I had to first get A1 without D1, then get it to just be the middle section using the LEFT formula, and then finally taking the LEN of that. Checked to see if it was equal to the =VALUE(MID(I4,10,1)), which was the next number in B1.

If that was true, I went to the final IF statement which again had to go through the same process of getting the last section of A1 on it's own, taking the length of that, and seeing if it was equal to =VALUE(MID(I4,11,1)).

Finally, I just created different print statements for the last true, and every false section of the IF statements.

Moral of the story, I was able to make a formula that works with every single number combination because it turns out B1 could only be in the form of AB - CDE###, so I could always find that number in B1 and compare it.

Comment: +1 for coming back and showing us your solution! I haven't tested it out but I hope you have, with lots of possible correct and incorrect input data. Also can I strongly recommend documenting how it works somewhere within your spreadsheet, perhaps on an extra 'docs' tab, so that you stand a chance of still understanding it when you need to come back and modify it in a couple of months' time ;)

Comment: You can use FormulaDesk http://www.formuladesk.com to easily understand formulas like this, without needing to break into multiple cells. [Disclosure: I wrote FormulaDesk]